# Concat in Excel using VBA and output it to a string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement where I am trying to concatenate the values from Cell A1 to M1. The sheets are dynamic.

I am trying to concatenate the values from cell A1 to M1 to a string using VBA.

How to do this ? The sheets are dynamic, so when we select the range I want the sheets to be mentioned in the code as well.

This is how excel generates a macro, if I do the concat on cell N1,

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCAT(RC[-13]:RC[-1])"
```

Thanks. Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: Where do you have the sheet name, in the code, in another cell?

Comment: What do you mean bu sheets are dynamic?  Do you create new sheets within the same spreadsheet or will you just change the name of the sheet every time?

Comment: I can actually take care of the sheet name. if you give the VBA Code that has the sheet mentioned in it as Sheet1 or something. Its just that, I want to output it to different strings in vba just by changing the sheet name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim str As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")   'change Sheet4 to your data sheet
    For Each cel In Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range("M1"))
        str = str & cel.Value
    Next cel
    Debug.Print str
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, Just what I wanted actually. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the sheet name added to the formula, but I don't understand why.

```
With ActiveCell
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCAT(" & .Parent.Name & "!RC[-13]:RC[-1])"
End With
```